# Consuming TaskGroup response

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In Python3.11 it's suggested to use `TaskGroup` for spawning Tasks rather than using `gather`. Given Gather will also return the result of a co-routine, what's the best approach with TaskGroup.

Currently I have

```py
async with TaskGroup() as tg:
      r1 = tg.create_task(foo())
      r2 = tg.create_task(bar())
res = [r1.result(), r2.result()]
```

Is there a more concise approach that can be used to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The task groups were implemented more as a cleaner way to handle task lifetimes and exception handling, enabled greatly by the new exceptions group rework. I think its a popular misconception right now, but the `TaskGroup` is not a drop in replacement for all of the `gather` use-cases. For cases where you do not care about the results (which seems to be the only example I am seeing in new documentation and tutorials) it feels much more terse.

When the task group has completed, it's still required by the user to pull results out of the completed coruntines. If you need values immediately then you can write it as you have it as `res = [r1.result(), r2.result()]` after the `TaskGroup` completes. A more terse syntax might be to gather the results after the `TaskGroup` completes with `res = await asyncio.gather(r1, r2)` (this will release the execution of your function which may or may not be desirable).

This may look redundant to use both `TaskGroup` and `gather`, but the `TaskGroup` is solving a different purpose than what is provided by `gather` alone, being that it allows for waiting for your tasks with strong safety guarantees, logic around cancellation for failures, and grouping of exceptions.

It might be possible to extend the default `TaskGroup` class to make this pattern easier. Here's one such idea that can keep track of which tasks were issued in the task group and provides a helper to fish out the results:

```
class GatheringTaskGroup(asyncio.TaskGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__tasks = []

    def create_task(self, coro, *, name=None, context=None):
        task = super().create_task(coro, name=name, context=context)
        self.__tasks.append(task)
        return task

    def results(self):
        return [task.result() for task in self.__tasks]
```

```
async def foo(): return 1
async def bar(): return 2
async with GatheringTaskGroup() as tg:
    task1 = tg.create_task(foo())
    task2 = tg.create_task(bar())
print(tg.results())
```

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it would be quite nice to extend taskgroups for this flow given the benefit with exception groups over gather

Comment: Would be nice if the stdlib would provide this.